# Get special characters from the key events

Tags: python, keyboard, pygame, special-characters

When a PyGame key event is fired, the letter associated with the key is gathered using `chr(event.key)`. This doesn’t work when a key with a special character is pressed, such as <kbd>æ</kbd>, <kbd>ø</kbd> or <kbd>å</kbd>, on a Norwegian keyboard.

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    characterNumber = event.key
    character = chr(characterNumber)
    print(character)
```

How can these characters be retrieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing this:

```
characterNumber = event.key
character = chr(characterNumber)
```

Try this:

```
character = event.unicode
```

According to the docs, a `KEYDOWN` event should have a unicode property which represents the unicode value of the key that was pressed, based on the current keyboard layout.

http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html